hadoop execute mapreduce error info: Failing the application
    2024-08-29 16:25:51,669 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2024-08-29 16:25:51,687 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1724916787445_0010 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1724916787445_0010 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1724916787445_0010_000002 exited with  exitCode: 255
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2024-08-29 16:25:51.030]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e54_1724916787445_0010_02_000002
Exit code: 255

[2024-08-29 16:25:51.032]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 255. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :

[2024-08-29 16:25:51.033]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 255. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :

For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://002.bg.qkt:8088/cluster/app/application_1724916787445_0010 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. **Failing the application.**
2024-08-29 16:25:51,720 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0

I collected all the information in the entire log and couldn't find any more
This is an error displayed by the webui:

2024-08-29 19:02:55,081 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl: App: application_1724926958492_0006 can't handle this event at current state
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.InvalidStateTransitionException: Invalid event: APP_UPDATE_SAVED at ACCEPTED
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$500(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:487)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl.handle(RMAppImpl.java:880)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.RMAppImpl.handle(RMAppImpl.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$ApplicationEventDispatcher.handle(ResourceManager.java:1006)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$ApplicationEventDispatcher.handle(ResourceManager.java:990)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:126)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

